# Блокировка обьекта

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex, lock

Как использовать блокировки **без создания mutex**?
Т.е. у меня есть некий объект:

```
int i = 0; //Не обязательно числовой тип
```

И я хочу выполнить его временную блокировку.

```
lock(i, []{
    i++;
});
```

Возможно ли? Или нужно создавать mutex к каждому объекту отдельно?

Comment: Есть спинлоки, есть всякие атомарные операции. Озвучьте, что Вы хотите делать, чем не устроил мьютекс и под какую ОС пишете

Comment: [std::atomic](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) - если у вас действительно просто int, и вы хотите его увеличить на единицу, может помочь.

Comment: В основном это std::stack, ос  - win, Unix(mac, linux, ..)

Comment: `В основном это std::stack`
Тогда mutex самый простой вариант